# Cleanest way in Scala to avoid nested ifs when transforming collections and checking for error conditions in each step

Tags: scala

I have some code for validating ip addresses that looks like the following:

```
sealed abstract class Result
case object Valid extends Result
case class Malformatted(val invalid: Iterable[IpConfig]) extends Result
case class Duplicates(val dups: Iterable[Inet4Address]) extends Result
case class Unavailable(val taken: Iterable[Inet4Address]) extends Result

def result(ipConfigs: Iterable[IpConfig]): Result = {
  val invalidIpConfigs: Iterable[IpConfig] =
    ipConfigs.filterNot(ipConfig => {
      (isValidIpv4(ipConfig.address)
        && isValidIpv4(ipConfig.gateway))
    })
  if (!invalidIpConfigs.isEmpty) {
    Malformatted(invalidIpConfigs)
  } else {
    val ipv4it: Iterable[Inet4Address] = ipConfigs.map { ipConfig =>
      InetAddress.getByName(ipConfig.address).asInstanceOf[Inet4Address]
    }
    val dups = ipv4it.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.size != 1).keys
    if (!dups.isEmpty) {
      Duplicates(dups)
    } else {
      val ipAvailability: Map[Inet4Address, Boolean] =
        ipv4it.map(ip => (ip, isIpAvailable(ip)))
      val taken: Iterable[Inet4Address] = ipAvailability.filter(!_._2).keys
      if (!taken.isEmpty) {
        Unavailable(taken)
      } else {
        Valid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't like the nested ifs because it makes the code less readable. Is there a nice way to linearize this code? In java, I might use return statements, but this is discouraged in scala.

Comment: I think the readability would be most improved by breaking out your (often optional) subcomputations to other functions.

Comment: `ipv4it.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.size != 1).keys` can be written as `(ipv4it diff ipv4it.distinct).distinct` (removing one of every distinct element leaves just duplicates, then the second distinct makes sure only one of each is left).

Comment: and taken can be `ipv4it.filter{isIpAvailable}`. I don't see why you go through the intermediate map (you have no duplicates so it's not eliminate those)

Answer (score 1):

I personally advocate using a match everywhere you can, as it in my opinion usually makes code very readable

```
def result(ipConfigs: Iterable[IpConfig]): Result =
  ipConfigs.filterNot(ipc => isValidIpv4(ipc.address) && isValidIpv4(ipc.gateway)) match {
    case Nil => 
      val ipv4it = ipConfigs.map { ipc =>
        InetAddress.getByName(ipc.address).asInstanceOf[Inet4Address]
      }
      ipv4it.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.size != 1).keys match {
        case Nil =>
          val taken = ipv4it.map(ip => (ip, isIpAvailable(ip))).filter(!_._2).keys
          if (taken.nonEmpty) Unavailable(taken) else Valid
        case dups => Duplicates(dups)
      }
    case invalid => Malformatted(invalid)
  }
```

Note that I've chosen to match on the `else` part first, since you generally go from specific to generic in matches, since [`Nil` is a subclass of `Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable) I put that as the first case, eliminating the need for an `i if i.nonEmpty` in the other `case`, since it would be a given if it didn't match `Nil`

Also a thing to note here, all your `val`s don't need the type explicitly defined, it significantly declutters the code if you write something like

```
val ipAvailability: Map[Inet4Address, Boolean] =
  ipv4it.map(ip => (ip, isIpAvailable(ip)))
```

as simply

```
val ipAvailability = ipv4it.map(ip => (ip, isIpAvailable(ip)))
```

I've also taken the liberty of removing many one-off variables I didn't find remotely necessary, as all they did was add more lines to the code

A thing to note here about using `match` over nested `if`s, is that is that it's easier to add a new `case` than it is to add a new `else if` 99% of the time, thereby making it more modular, and modularity is always a good thing.

Alternatively, as suggested by Nathaniel Ford, you can break it up into several smaller methods, in which case the above code would look like so:

```
def result(ipConfigs: Iterable[IpConfig]): Result =
  ipConfigs.filterNot(ipc => isValidIpv4(ipc.address) && isValidIpv4(ipc.gateway)) match {
    case Nil => wellFormatted(ipConfigs)
    case i => Malformatted(i)
  }

def wellFormatted(ipConfigs: Iterable[IpConfig]): Result = {
  val ipv4it = ipConfigs.map(ipc => InetAddress.getByName(ipc.address).asInstanceOf[Inet4Address])
  ipv4it.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.size != 1).keys match {
    case Nil => noDuplicates(ipv4it)          
    case dups => Duplicates(dups)
  }
}

def noDuplicates(ipv4it: Iterable[IpConfig]): Result = 
  ipv4it.map(ip => (ip, isIpAvailable(ip))).filter(!_._2).keys match {
    case Nil => Valid
    case taken => Unavailable(taken)
  }
```

This has the benefit of splitting it up into smaller more manageable chunks, while keeping to the FP ideal of having functions that only do one thing, but do that one thing well, rather than having god-methods that do everything.

Which style you prefer, of course is up to you.

Comment: You have a method `wellFormatted` which is nothing to do with being well formatted and `noDuplicates` which tests availability :( Naming functions after their preconditions is, er, unusual.

Comment: I just figured it fit since `noDuplicates` is the opposite of `Duplicates` and `wellFormatted` is the opposite of `Malformatted` in that sense it fits, but I dunno

Answer (score 1):

This has some time now but I will add my 2 cents. The proper way to handle this is with Either. You can create a method like:

```
def checkErrors[T](errorList: Iterable[T], onError: Result) : Either[Result, Unit] = if(errorList.isEmpty) Right() else Left(onError)
```

so you can use for comprehension syntax

```
val invalidIpConfigs = getFormatErrors(ipConfigs)

val result = for {
  _ <- checkErrors(invalidIpConfigs, Malformatted(invalidIpConfigs))
  dups = getDuplicates(ipConfigs)
  _ <- checkErrors(dups, Duplicates(dups))
  taken = getAvailability(ipConfigs)
  _ <- checkErrors(taken, Unavailable(taken))
} yield Valid
```

If you don't want to return an Either use

```
result.fold(l => l, r => r)
```

In case of the check methods uses Futures (could be the case for getAvailability, for example), you can use cats library to be able of use it in a clean way: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it's pretty readable and I wouldn't try to improve it from there, except that `!isEmpty` equals to `nonEmpty`.